# Show random price to certain visitors based on IP-address

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, ip-address

Is there any easy way to let my Magento store display different price based on a visitor's IP address?

The reason I'd like to do this is that I have one specific competitor who constantly compare with my prices just to lower his own somewhere below - and I would like to distract him by showing random prices. And I know his IP. Displaying random + 10-20% higher prices to him would be helpful.

Comment: Yes this can be possible. we will show prices with extra addition of 10-20 % to actual prices.

send me your email id.

Comment: You'd probably need an observer somewhere in the `getPrice()` process, you'd need to identify him by his IP and you'd need to muck around with the price from your observer

Comment: @Paarth - please email me at mrfirewall@hotmail.com